# Bitmasking to get individual bytes

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am trying to walk through an array of uint64_t's

ie:

```
const uint64_t data[] =
{
    0x0000000000000000,
    0x1111111111111111,
    0x2322323232323232
}
```

From this I would like to walk through each index in the array and of each index, print the value of each byte. I think a bitmask would be the way to do it, but I can't quite get this right...I have this so far:

```
static const int indices = sizeof(data) / sizeof(uint64_t);
uint64_t mask;

for(int i= 0; i < indices; i++)
{
    mask = 0xff;
    for(int byte = 0; byte < 8; byte++)
    {
        printf("index[%d], byte[%d]: 0x%02x\n", i, byte, data | mask);
        mask = mask << 8;
        printf("mask: 0x%016lx\n", mask);
    }
}
```

My output is as expected for the mask. It is shifting 8 bits(1 byte) each loop through. The bitwise data comparison is goofy, however. The bit-wise AND seems to be working correctly, the format however is not. I am looking for print statements that just hold the byte value, not a uint64_t val as it is now. 
I think that having the mask as a uin64_t is messing up the printing of the single byte value, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I am getting feedback like this: 
data[1] byte[1]: 0x1100
but want to get my data in a form like:
data[1] byte[1]: 0x11

Comment: I added the `C` tag to your question, since it looks like you are using C (which I haven't used in about 10 years...I'll be leaving now).

Comment: Ah, totally spaced that. Thanks!

Comment: What bitwise AND, you have an OR there

Comment: Thanks Harold...apparantly need to get better at updating as I catch things myself. I noticed that a couple minutes after posting. I have it working now...Does stackoverflow etiquette suggest editing my original post code or making a new comment/answer?

Comment: @kennedyl edit, maybe leave a comment to avoid making answers into non-sequiturs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You evidently have at least three problems here:

1. You use a bitwise "or" (`|`) where you want bitwise "and" (`&`).
2. You are using `data` where you want an *element* of `data`.  Your particular use oughtn't even to compile, as pointers are not allowed operands for bitwise arithmetic operators.
3. You fail to shift the data / masked data.

You also claim in comments on another answer that even after correcting those errors you get output with many leading zeroes.  I cannot replicate that result with GCC, but I do observe that it is essential for the field descriptor to designate the correct type for the argument.  Your argument is a `uint64_t`, and in most C systems that does not correspond to `unsigned int`, which is what the field descriptor `x` expects when no length modifiers are provided.  If extra leading zeroes are presented even when everything matches up correctly, then it may be that your implementation of `x` is outputting a representation of all the bytes, without truncating leading zeroes.  In that case, you could try specifying the argument to be (and in fact making it be) an `unsigned char`.

Putting that all together, you want something more like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices; i++)
{
    for(int byte = 0; byte < 64; byte += 8)
    {
        printf("index[%d], byte[%d]: 0x%02hhx\n", i, byte,
            (unsigned char) ((data[i] >> byte) & 0xff));
    }
}
```

That shifts the data to match it to the mask instead of shifting the mask to select the data, because the latter would require the result to be shifted anyway.  I assume the indexing and use of the correct operator need no further explanation.

Do, however, note also the field descriptor and the cast.  `%02hhx` says the field is to be zero-padded (`0`) and a minimum of two characters wide (`2`).  The corresponding argument is of an unsigned integer type to be presented in hexadecimal form (`x`), and in particular, it is an `unsigned char` (`hh`).  The corresponding argument is cast to `unsigned char` to match.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing you can do if you want to have the single byte values is to right shift `data` instead of shifting `mask`. As @harold has correcty mentioned, 'oring' a byte with 0xff makes no sense.

```
for(int i= 0; i < indices; i++)
{
    uint64_t val = data[i];
    for(int byte = 0; byte < 8; byte++)
    {
        printf("index[%d], byte[%d]: 0x%02x\n", i, byte, val & 0xff );
        val >>= 8;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Btw, `((val & 0xff) | 0xff) == 0xff`